# Controlling a game externally

Tags: macros, gaming

Is there software to automate the menu-controls of a game (Project Cars 2)?

In detail: We want to use Project Cars 2 in our game hall and therefore we are looking for a way to automatically start a new game after the last one finishes. Are there interfaces we can use or something else?

OS: Windows 10

Price not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Cars appears to have an API ([Documented here](https://www.projectcarsgame.com/project-cars-2-api/)).
If that is too technical for you, you can automate the mouse/keyboard menu navigation with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) (free open source computer input automation scripting language).  (Website is down right now, but this is a hugely popular, well documented scripting platform)